Can you heat the air in a box to heat plastic inside box?
I am working on a project where I need to heat the air inside a box to heat up a 3d print inside it. As of now, I am using a heat gun to heat up the air.
I was wondering two things:

How can I add hot air to the box without the box exploding, as  I still want to keep the hot air inside, and not be constantly letting it out?
For this project I would rather use a peltier to heat air than a heat gun since they take up less space. However, I have not been able to find a cheap one that has a max temperature of at least 80 celsius. therefore, I was wondering if anyone knows about a good, cheap peltier.


yes, I can ... how is that answer useful to you?


don't add air to the box ... 2. some people know  .... please ask a question about the problem, not about people's knowledge


any reason not to use a resistive heater?

"good, cheap" don't occur in the same sentence when looking for reliable working solutions.

Get some nichrome wire and make your own resistive heater- the heating element inside the heat gun is likely that. Make a box sturdy if you don't want it to explode?

resistive heater and a recirculating fan is the way to go - otherwise known as a fan oven...
